# Error converting Unix timestamp to int - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am writing a Django Framework app that receives Unix Timestamps as parameters in an Ajax call and uses them to query a database. My issue is in converting the timestamp strings to Python ints, which throws ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. This is the snippet:

```
start = request.GET.get('start','')
start = int(start)
```

I tried printing the timestamp and copying the output into a shell for the same operation, which completed successfully:

```
>>> int(1485939600)
1485939600
```

The error suggests it's being passed an empty string yet I can print it. Not sure what the problem could be?

Comment: Print the `repr` of the string in question. Odds are, it has non-printing character embedded in it, e.g. `\0`, that don't show up in the "friendly" `print` output, but would show as the relevant escapes if you wrap it in `repr()`.

Comment: why do you have `.get('start','')`?  This implies that it is OK for the `'start'` field to be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I found the problem was elsewhere, the AJAX call was being made without parameters on pageload, passing an empty string to int().

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of get is the default value if the query parameter 'start' does not exist

```
start = request.GET.get('start','')
```

Empty string cannot be transformed in an Int.

```
start = request.GET.get('start',0)
```

Will default to 1970 if there is no start param